# Is it possible to store and query JSON in SQLite?

Tags: sqlite, json

I need to store JSON objects in a SQLite database, 
and then do complex queries on it.

I did a table like this:

```
+--------------------------------------+
|document |  property | string | number|
+--------------------------------------+
|foo      |  "title"  | "test" |       | 
+--------------------------------------+
|foo      |  "id"     |        |  42   | 
+--------------------------------------+
|bar      |  "id"     |        |  43   | 
+--------------------------------------+
```

for the two objects

```
foo {"title": "test", "id": 42} 
bar {id: 43}
```

But I can't do "AND" queries, like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT id  FROM table WHERE title = "test" AND id = 42
```

as you see, the part after the "WHERE" is total nonsense, 
but I have no idea of how to create a query that would do what I want.

So do you think there is a better way to store my data,
or a workaround  to do an "AND" query?

And of course, the JSON can contain any property,
so I can't create a table with columns for each properties.

I am using WebSQL, which is SQLite without extensions.

I know my question is pretty specific, but could you help me?

Comment: If that is really important for your application you are probably better off using either a real document store ("NoSQL") or e.g. switch to Postgres which combines very efficient JSON storage with strong relational features.

Comment: Read [the documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/json1.html).

Comment: You have to accounts and should merge them: http://dba.stackexchange.com/users/81459/tuxlu and http://dba.stackexchange.com/users/81513/tuxlu You can use this help page: http://dba.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts

Comment: Aside from the problem of using JSON natively in a database, the example database is not normalized. So of course, this makes a select query problematic. Instead of having (document, property, string, number), it should be (document, property, type, value) with value parsed at runtime. From there, it is trivial to create a json object manually.

One can opt for "native" json support (like sqllite JSON extensions), but that just masks a deeper design issue IMO.

Answer (score 54):

SQLite 3.9 introduced a new extension ([JSON1](https://www.sqlite.org/json1.html)) that allows you to easily work with JSON data .

Also, it introduced support for indexes on [expressions](http://sqlite.org/expridx.html), which (in my understanding) should allow you to define indexes on your JSON data as well.

Answer (score 10):

PostgreSQL has some nice features for JSON storage. You can select the JSON values by doing

```
SELECT DISTINCT FROM TABLE WHERE foo->title=test AND id=42
```

You can also index the specific keys on the JSON object if you use the `jsonb` type.

Comment: Is there any 1:1 equivalent to this in Sqlite3 these days in 2020+?

Comment: Doesn't answer OP question... not about PG

Comment: Did you consider that maybe OP was already using Postgres in production and wanted to mimic PSQL's capabilities for testing ?

Comment: @NickSweeting in 2022 the `->` and `->>` operators work in sqlite https://www.sqlite.org/json1.html#jptr `select foo->'title' from atable`

Answer (score 7):

The existing answers for this deal with actually storing the OP's data as JSON (which may have been a better solution to his underlying problem).

However, the actual question was how to get find documents in the EAV-style table provided, based on multiple properties. So, perhaps an answer to that question would be useful.

The standard SQL way of doing what you are saying is INTERSECTION.

```
(SELECT document FROM table WHERE property="id" AND number=43)
INTERSECTION 
(SELECT document FROM table WHERE property="title" AND string="test")
```

You can also do this with self joins if you prefer.

```
SELECT t1.document
FROM table as t1, table as t2
WHERE t1.document = t2.document
AND t1.property="id" AND t1.number=43
AND t2.property="title" AND t2.string="test"
```

Of course the more "correct" and arguably most efficient way would be to just make a column for each property you need, like 'id' and 'title'.

Answer (score 1):

You can import the json into a table with a single row and one column and use the built in json functions to extract the values you need.

Based on the given SQL

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT id  FROM table WHERE title = "test" AND id = 42
```

and the provided `foo` object

```json
{"title": "test", "id": 42}
```

I assume that you have an array of json objects like this

```json
[
  {"title": "test 1", "id": 42},
  {"title": "test 2", "id": 43}
]
```

In my case i had a [pmd](https://docs.pmd-code.org/latest/index.html) json output with an array of json objects (`[finding-1, finding-2]`). Each array element `finding` contains another json object `code` which contains another json object `target`

```
array : [
   finding-1 { ... }
                 |
                 |--- code : { ... }
                        |
                        |--- target { ... }
   ,finding-2 { ... }
   ,finding-3 { ... }
]
```

similar to this

```json
[
 {"resource": "/C:/src/one.cls",
  "code": {
        "value": "AvoidGlobalModifier",
        "target": {
            "path": "/latest/pmd_rules_apex_bestpractices.html",
            "fragment": "avoidglobalmodifier"
        }
    },
    "severity": 4,
    "message": "Avoid using global modifier ..."
},
{"resource": "/C:/src/two.cls",
    "code": {
        "value": "ApexSOQLInjection",
        "target": {
            "path": "/latest/pmd_rules_apex_bestpractices.html",
            "fragment": "apexsoqlinjection"
        }
    },
    "severity": 4,
    "message": "... escape variables merged in DML query ..."
}]
```

I created table `pmd_report` where i copied the json-array into the column `pmd_output` in a single record. The table looks like this

```sql
CREATE TABLE "pmd_report" (
    "id"    INTEGER,
    "import_date"   TEXT,
    "pmd_output"    TEXT
)
```

To extract the values from the json array and the json objects this SQL statement can be used

```
SELECT 
    json_extract(json_parsed, '$.code.target.fragment') as code_target_fragment, 
    json_extract(json_parsed, '$.severity') as severity, 
    json_extract(json_parsed, '$.message') as message, 
    json_extract(json_parsed, '$.resource') as resource, 
    json_extract(json_parsed, '$.code.value') as code_value, 
    json_extract(json_parsed, '$.code.target.path') as code_target_path 
FROM (
    SELECT jsonEach.Value as json_parsed
        FROM pmd_report,json_each(pmd_report.pmd_output, '$') as jsonEach 
) as subquery;
```

To store the extracted json you can insert the rows into a new table like this

```sql
INSERT INTO pmd_report_2 (fragment, severity, message, startLineNumber, endLineNumber, 
        resource, 
        code_value, 
        code_target_path
        )
SELECT code_target_fragment, severity, message, 
       startLineNumber, endLineNumber, substr(resource, 43) as resource, 
       code_value,  code_target_path
FROM (
    SELECT 
        json_extract(json_parsed, '$.code.target.fragment') as code_target_fragment, 
        json_extract(json_parsed, '$.severity') as severity, 
        json_extract(json_parsed, '$.message') as message, 
        json_extract(json_parsed, '$.startLineNumber') as startLineNumber,
        json_extract(json_parsed, '$.endLineNumber') as endLineNumber,
        json_extract(json_parsed, '$.resource') as resource, 
        json_extract(json_parsed, '$.code.value') as code_value, 
        json_extract(json_parsed, '$.code.target.path') as code_target_path 
    FROM (
            SELECT jsonEach.Value as json_parsed
            FROM pmd_report,json_each(pmd_report.pmd_output, '$') as jsonEach 
    ) as subquery ) 
as subquery_2;
```